# c# windows app login without SQL

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

I'm writing a c# windows application that requires a login which I was planning to simply check using a sql select from my web server, however my webhost appears to only allow remote sql access if you manually enter your IP address which I can't do for every user of the app.

So my question is, what would be the best solution around this? I've considered trying a httprequest to a page on my website which in turn could then check the login details passed to it with PHP and pass back a result but it needs to be secure and this looks like a bit of a pain to implement (im fairly new to c#).

Comment: What do you mean by "manually enter your IP address"? Of the server? Or the user?

Comment: **Edit:** Dumb question, of course you mean the user. For security reasons alone, you would never want any user with that application to be able to hit up your sql server for login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

As said in my comment above, for security reasons alone, you would never want any user with that application to have access to your sql server. My suggestion is to have the client connect via SSL (https://) to an ASP.NET page or web service that will check the credentials provided using LINQ to SQL. It can then send the client a pass/fail response.

Oh, and for the love of god and all that is holy, [salt and hash your users' passwords](http://goo.gl/NyucS).

**Note:** If you're wanting to use this login to prevent the user from using your app without having an account/paying, all the above stands, but will not be sufficient to stop people from reverse engineering and cracking the app (e.g., tricking it into thinking that it's received the pass message). That sort of DRM is a whole 'nother ballgame.